# Convert list of Integers into one Int (like concat) in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, integer

Pretty much what the title says. I have a list of Integers like so: [1,2,3]. I want to change this in to the Integer 123. My first thought was concat but that doesn't work because it's of the wrong type, I've tried various things but usually I just end up returning the same list. Any help greatly appreciated.

Also I *have* found a way to print the right thing (putStr) except I want the type to be Integer and putStr doesn't do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`foldl`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:foldl) to combine all the elements of a list:

```
fromDigits = foldl addDigit 0
   where addDigit num d = 10*num + d
```

The `addDigit` function is called by `foldl` to add the digits, one after another, starting from the leftmost one.

```
*Main> fromDigits [1,2,3]
123
```

**Edit:**
`foldl` walks through the list from left to right, adding the elements to accumulate some value.

The second argument of `foldl`, `0` in this case, is the starting value of the process. In the first step, that starting value is combined with `1`, the first element of the list, by calling `addDigit 0 1`. This results in 10*0+1 = 1. In the next step this 1 is combined with the second element of the list, by `addDigit 1 2`, giving 10*1+2 = 12. Then this is combined with the third element of the list, by `addDigit 12 3`, resulting in 10*12+3 = 123.

So pointlessly multiplying by zero is just the first step, in the following steps the multiplication is actually needed to add the new digits "to the end" of the number getting accumulated.

Comment: Or way cooler point free - fromDigits = foldl ((+).(*10)) 0 :)

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. This was what I thinking I'd have to do but you've done it much nicer than I could so thanks!

Comment: So it works, but I'm not exactly sure how the addDigit part works. I know foldl takes a function and a list does that on all the elements of the list.. but addDigit seems to multiply 0 (num) by 10 and then add the element.. which would just be adding the element.. so what am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that `foldl` accumulates as it goes--0 is used the first time, and the result is used the second time, etc. So it's `addDigit 0 1` = 1, `addDigit 1 2` = 12, `addDigit 12 3` = 123

Comment: If someone felt strongly enough about the pointless 0, they could remove it and use `foldl1` instead.  And perhaps that's easier to explain?  `1 addDigit 2 addDigit 3`, if `addDigit` were a left-associative infix operator.  Then again, having the 0 in front doesn't change a thing...

Comment: Ah I get it now I was just forgetting that it's accumulative. Thanks!

Comment: To make this work for multiple-digit numbers, you just need to change the 10 in `addDigit` to `(10 ^ (floor $ log (fromIntegral d) / log 10 + 1))`. It looks a little ugly, but all it's doing is adjusting 10 by the magnitude of the number.

Comment: This doesn't do the right thing for multidigit numbers. Chuck's solution works, but the basic idea of what is going on is better expressed in Ashutosh Mehra's solution -- directly smashing together the textual representation.

Comment: Use `foldl'` instead. Found in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 12):

You could `concat` the string representations of the numbers, and then `read` them back, like so:

```
joiner :: [Integer] -> Integer
joiner = read . concatMap show
```

Comment: This turns `[12,34]` into `1234` -- unlike sth's, which turns it into `154`, or Chris's, which errors out.  OP's desired behavior is not specified enough.

Comment: sth's works because I'm only ever using 1 digit numbers. This is also the way I'd like it to work.. but could someone explain precisely how the addDigit works in sth's?

Answer (score 4):

This worked pretty well for me.

```
read (concat (map show (x:xs))) :: Int
```

How function reads: 
Step 1 - convert each int in the list to a string
`(map show (x:xs))` 
Step 2 - combine each of those strings together
`(concat (step 1))` 
Step 3 - read the string as the type of int
`read (step 2) :: Int`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`read`](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/read_f.html) and also [`intToDigit`](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputchar/intToDigit_f.html):

```
joinInt :: [Int] -> Int
joinInt l = read $ map intToDigit l
```

Has the advantage (or disadvantage) of puking on multi-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to say: the last digit counts for 1, the next-to last counts for 10, the digit before that counts for 100, etcetera. So to convert a list of digits to a number, you need to reverse it (in order to start at the back), multiply the digits together with the corresponding powers of ten, and add the result together.

To reverse a list, use `reverse`, to get the powers of ten you can use `iterate (*10) 1` (try it in GHCi or Hugs!), to multiply corresponding digits of two lists use `zipWith (*)` and to add everything together, use `sum` - it really helps to know a few library functions! Putting the bits together, you get

```
fromDigits xs = sum (zipWith (*) (reverse xs) (iterate (*10) 1))
```

Example of evaluation:

```
fromDigits [1,2,3,4]  
    ==> sum (zipWith (*) (reverse [1,2,3,4]) [1,10,100,1000, ....]
    ==> sum (zipWith (*) [4,3,2,1] [1,10,100,1000, ....])
    ==> sum [4 * 1, 3 * 10, 2 * 100, 1 * 1000]
    ==> 4 + 30 + 200 + 1000
    ==> 1234
```

However, this solution is slower than the ones with `foldl`, due to the call to `reverse` and since you're building up those powers of ten only to use them directly again. On the plus side, this way of building numbers is closer to the way people usually think (at least I do!), while the `foldl`-solutions in essence use [Horner's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_rule).

Comment: Is that list valid syntax in GHC? All I've got here is Hugs, and it sure doesn't work there.

Comment: No, that list is just for explaining what (part of) the result of `iterate (*10) 1` looks like. It doesn't work in GHC either.

Answer (score 1):

```
join :: Integral a => [a] -> a
join [x] = x
join (x:xs) = (x * (10 ^ long)) + join(xs)
    where long = length(x:xs)
```

We can define the function called `join`, that given a list of Integral numbers it can return another Integral number. We are using recursion to separate the head of the given list with the rest of the list and we use pattern matching to define an edge condition so that the recursion can end.

Comment: is it not where long = length(x:s) - 1. When I tested as is it appended an extra zero because the power was too high

Answer (score 0):

As for how to print the number, instead of

```
putStr n
```

just try

```
putStr (show n)
```

The reasoning is that `putStr` can only print strings. So you need to convert the number to a string before passing it in.

You may also want to try the `print` function from Prelude. This one can print anything that is "showable" (any instance of class `Show`), not only Strings. But be aware that `print n` corresponds (roughly) to `putStrLn (show n)`, not `putStr (show n)`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert in Haskell, but this is the easiest way I can think of for a solution to this problem that doesn't involve using any other external functions.

```
concatDigits :: [Int] -> Int
concatDigits [] = 0
concatDigits xs = concatReversed (reverseDigits xs) 1

reverseDigits :: [Int] -> [Int]
reverseDigits [] = []
reverseDigits (x:xs) = (reverseDigits xs) ++ [x]

concatReversed :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
concatReversed [] d = 0
concatReversed (x:xs) d = (x*d) + concatReversed xs (d*10)
```

As you can see, I've assumed you're trying to concat a list of digits. If by any chance this is not your case, I'm pretty sure this won't work. :(

In my solution, first of all I've defined a function called `reverseDigits`, which reverses the original list. For example [1,2,3] to [3,2,1]

After that, I use a `concatReversed` function which takes a list of digits and number d, which is the result of ten power the first digit on the list position. If the list is empty it returns 0, and if not, it returns the first digit on the list times d, plus the call to `concatReversed` passing the rest of the list and d times 10.

Hope the code speaks for itself, because I think my poor English explanation wasn't very helpful.

---

### Edit

After a long time, I see my solution is very messy, as it requires reversing the list in order to be able to multiply each digit by 10 power the index of the digit in the list, from right to left. Now knowing tuples, I see that a much better approach is to have a function that receives both the accumulated converted part, and the remainder of the list, so in each invocation in multiplies the accumulated part by 10, and then adds the current digit.

```
concatDigits :: [Int] -> Int
concatDigits xs = aggregate (xs, 0)
  where aggregate :: ([Int], Int) -> Int
        aggregate ([], acc) = acc
        aggregate (x:xs, acc) = aggregate (xs, (acc * 10 + x))
```

Comment: -1: Non-constructor functions are lowercase. Also not very intuitive IMO.

Comment: I believe this is a perfectly valid answer. I was clear about I'm no expert in Haskell, so don't kill me if I don't know the coding conventions.

Comment: it is not just a coding convention. trying to define a function with a capitalized name, e.g. *`F 1 = 1`* actually results in an error: *"Not in scope: data constructor `F' "*.

Comment: Hi @ThomasEding. I lowered the function names as an attempt to make peace. Let me highlight again I'm no expert in Haskell, not by a very long far.
I'm sorry you didn't find my answer intuitive enough, even though I tried to provide enough detail in my explanation. I as a learner, find more useful my own answer, than relying on foldl, concat, map, zip or any other external function.
I saw a question about something I was toying around a long time ago and treated it as a puzzle to solve. I don't even remember what I used in order to run and test the code.

Comment: Hi @WillNess. I lowered the function names as an attempt to make peace. Let me highlight again I'm no expert in Haskell, not by a very long far.
I saw a question about something I was toying around a long time ago and treated it as a puzzle to solve. I don't even remember what I used in order to run and test the code.